# Can't gzdecode on base64decode from soap response

Tags: php, soap, base64, gzip

I got a problem with this SOAP response :

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Body>
        <GetStockResponse xmlns="http://retailexpress.com.au/">
          <GetStockResult>base64Binary</GetStockResult>
        </GetStockResponse>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

So, my code for handle this response look like this :

```php
    public function getStock()
    {

        $soapClient = $this->getSoapClient();

        $xmlRequest = soapHead . '<ret:GetStock></ret:GetStock>' . soapFoot;

        try {
            $request = $soapClient->__anotherRequest('GetStock', $xmlRequest);
            $requestDecoded = base64_decode($request);
            $stock = gzdecode($requestDecoded);
        } catch (SoapFault $e ){
            var_dump($e);
            exit();
        }

        $response = new Response($stock);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

        return $response;

    }
```

With this code I always got this error :

```
Warning: gzdecode(): data error
```

But if I var_dump $request decoded and I try to gzdecode this string it works !

I can't find my mistake here ...
And for each try I got to wait 5 minutes ^^'

I hope I'm enough understandable

Thanks by advance

Tanguy

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution,
The soap response is an xml so you need to create a SimpleXmlElement to get the content

```
        $request = $soapClient->__anotherRequest('GetStock', $xmlRequest);
        $xmlRequest     = new \SimpleXMLElement($request);
        $response = $xmlRequest->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')->Body->children()->GetStockResponse;
        $result = (string) $response->GetStockResult;

        $requestDecoded = base64_decode($result);
        $stock = gzdecode($requestDecoded);
```